# How can I update the time from chosen timezone every minute on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I have a jquery function that uses moment.js to calculate time in different timezone based on the clock in the client's system:

```
function updateTime(){
                var chicago = moment.tz("America/Chicago").format('h:mm:ss A');
               $('#time').html( chicago +", ");
            };

            moment.tz.add('America/Chicago|CST CDT|60 50|01010101010101010101010|1BQU0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0');                                                                         

            updateTime();
            setInterval(function(){
               updateTime();
            },1000);
```

It works pretty nice, however when user changes his system clock, then the momentjs shows incorrect time. I figured out I can fetch timestamp from the server (by php) and use it as a start time for updating time on client's webpage. I tried to write a script as follows:

```
function updateTimeBasedOnServer(){
                var timestamp = 1443618723;
                var Chicago = new Date(timestamp);
                var dateString = Chicago.format('h:mm:ss A');
               $('#time2').html( dateString +", ");
            };


            updateTimeBasedOnServer();
            setInterval(function(){
               updateTimeBasedOnServer();
            },1000);
```

But it doesn't work. I want to have the same result as after running the first script, but with only the difference that it works independently from the user's clock in his system. How can I do that?
Here is my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error here:

```
function updateTimeBasedOnServer(){
            var timestamp = 1443618723;
            var Chicago = new Date(timestamp); // Here you create a Date object
            var dateString = Chicago.format('h:mm:ss A'); // a Date object does not have a 'format' method. A moment.js object has it.
           $('#time2').html( dateString +", ");
};
```

To fix it, use a moment.js object:

```
function updateTimeBasedOnServer() {
    var timestamp = 1443618723;
    var Chicago = moment(timestamp); // <- Here I create a moment.js object from the time stamp
    var dateString = Chicago.format('h:mm:ss A');
    $('#time2').html(dateString + ", ");
};
```

Here you can find a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aforni/b8o5cvdz/11/) with the working code.

**To answer you second question in the comment:**

> Thanks, one more thing - the 2nd date does not refresh every second -
>   is there a way of fixing it?

You should not hard code the timestamp value (1443618723) inside the `updateTimeBasedOnServer()` because at every call it will use that value. For this reason you do not see the time change.

To fix it, move the timestamp outside the method:

```
function updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp) { // Take in input the timestamp
    var Chicago = moment(timestamp);
    var dateString = Chicago.format('h:mm:ss A');
    $('#time2').html(dateString + ", ");
};

var timestamp = 1443618723;
updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp);
setInterval(function () {
    timestamp += 1000; // Increment the timestamp at every call.
    updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp);
}, 1000);
```

Se the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aforni/b8o5cvdz/13/) with the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing - the 2nd date does not refresh every second - is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: It does not update because every seconds it calls the `updateTimeBasedOnServer` method and use always the value as `1443618723 ` as `timestamp`. You cannot hardcode it in the method.

Comment: oh yeah, I see it, thanks! :) one more thing - can I use it as a start time and then append seconds, so that I don't need to make an ajax call to my php script?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, after you have the correct base time from the server you can increment it locally without call the server every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .toTimeString() or similar on the Date object, not .format

```
function updateTimeBasedOnServer(){
            var timestamp = 1443618723;
            var Chicago = new Date(timestamp);
            var dateString = Chicago.toTimeString();
           $('#time2').html( dateString +", ");
        };
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/10/)

Comment: thanks - one quetion - is it ok to create a new date object every second? Is it efficient?